# How to uninstall MySQL 5.7 installed through MacPorts?

Tags: mysql, uninstallation, macports, macos-sierra, mysql-5.7

Using this [MacPorts guide](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MySQL), I installed MySQL 5.7 on my Mac.

I want to uninstall it now but I can't find any documentation specific to removing just the MySQL server I installed through MacPorts.

I found [this guide](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/uninstall-mysql-mac-os-x) and others similar to it on how to completely remove MySQL on a Mac, and followed every single step listed.

However, when I issue the command, `sudo port load mysql57-server`, I can still load the MySQL server.

So how can I completely remove MySQL 5.7 installed through MacPorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's really simple - `sudo port uninstall mysql57-server`.

That removed MySQL 5.7 installed through MacPorts.

Comment: Ah, the simple joys of life.. was just about to comment that when I saw you already figured it out yourself.

Comment: @SB87 Believe me, I facepalmed myself so hard when I realized what I had to do.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't really remove the DB... If I reinstall it afterwards and try to initialize it complains that there are existing files